# AVPLAYER VIDEO BUFFER FULL??? (How To Reset/Empty The Buffer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

So I'm using AVPlayerViewController and what i'm doing to load the video is basically this:

I have a large number of videos in my database, I make a call to the db to retrieve the next video after the current video has finished playing, the issue I think may have to do with the buffer being full? After looking around on stack & the internet I couldn't find an answer that helped me.

I'm trying to find out how can I reset the buffer after each video is played, or atleast know when the buffer is out of space so that I can display an image or something while the buffer loads, so then I can make a call to continue displaying videos. Below is my code for the AVPlayerViewController.

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController 
alloc] init];

playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer @"www.videoURL.com"];

self.avPlayerViewcontroller = playerViewController;

[playerViewController.view setFrame: userView.bounds];

[userView addSubview:playerViewController.view];

self.avPlayerViewcontroller.player.volume = 0.0;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(volumeChanged:) 
name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" 
object:nil];


[playerViewController.player play];
[userImageView setHidden:NO];
```

Edit:1) I'm about to play about 15-25 videos before the video play gives me this:

[image]

Edit:2) But if I close the app and then re-open it, the videos play on the app like nothings wrong. I'm not really sure whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that encounters this same scenario, The issue for me was inside of the the same block that I was making my API call I was initializing this:

```
 AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = 
[[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
```

AVPlayerViewController was (STRONG) reference causing a retain cycle within the block, so each time I made an API call to grab a new video I was init a whole new AVPlayerViewController without releasing the previous. Along with that, I found that I had other objects within the API success response were being referenced strong as well. So I went back made those a WEAK reference and then I moved

```
 AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = 
[[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
```

To the view did load method, so it's initialized ONCE instead of everytime a new video URL comes through.

It took me all day to figure out what was going one, because after looking at other users having problems with this, I was so focused on "BUFFERING" or running out of buffering was the culprit, but comes to find out it was just bad implementation of objects and misplacements.

Good luck to future programmers.